# What purpose does a public module serve when one or more functions need to be public for this to have any effect?

Tags: rust

What purpose does `pub` in front of a module declaration in Rust serve?

All the members of a module are private by default, irrespective of whether a module is public or private (the default).

In order for a member of a module to be public, that entity (function, etc) must be declared public using `pub` also.

Hence it appears that the scope (public or private) of a module is redundant. Is this the case?

Reference: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-03-paths-for-referring-to-an-item-in-the-module-tree.html

Comment: If the module is private, you cannot access the public items inside it.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Hence the question

Comment: What is the question then? You need to make the module public so you'll be able to access the things inside.

Comment: It depends. Are you building a *library* which needs to *selectively expose* the modules it defines, or an *application* which just needs to *use* the modules it defines?

Answer (score 3):

This question makes perfect sense if it's coming from someone who mostly writes applications. There isn't much difference.

But I write libraries for a living (not in Rust unfortunately, but the same considerations apply), so the difference matters a lot to *me*.

Let's say I have a crate `Foo` and it has two modules, creatively named `Bar` and `Baz`, and each one has public function `f` and private function `g` but `Baz` is private:

```
pub mod Bar {
  pub fn f() -> () {}
  fn g() -> () {}
}

mod Baz {
  pub fn f() -> () {}
  fn g() -> () {}
}
```

So in this setup:

- `Bar::g` and `Baz::g` are local to their respective modules, I can't e.g. call them in main.
- `Bar::f` and `Baz::f` are public in their modules, I can e.g. call them from main.
- `Bar::f` is public *to consumers of my crate* (i.e. is part of my public API), they can call `Foo::Bar::f`, but crucially **not** `Foo::Baz::f`.

That last bit is the important part, and if you don't regularly work on libraries intended for other developers (or even intended for yourself to use in multiple projects) it's an easy distinction to miss.

Comment: To clarify a bit here, where is `main`? Because if I understand correctly you cannot call `Baz::f` from outside of the same module?

Comment: No you absolutely can call it in the same crate if it's part of the module tree. Think about how we do `use` declarations to include files in `main.rs` or `lib.rs`: you can say `use Baz;` and then call `Baz::f` but if you want someone *using your crate* to be able to call something you have to say `pub mod Whatever`. Consider the following code from [serde](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/blob/fccb9499bccbaca0b7eef91a3a82dfcb31e0b149/serde/src/lib.rs#L308) you can see it declaring `pub mod de` and `pub mod ser` for external consumers and elsewhere using private modules.

Comment: You may find the info in the module cheat sheet in the rust book helpful: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-02-defining-modules-to-control-scope-and-privacy.html#modules-cheat-sheet

Comment: There is a small catch: you *can* call `Foo::Baz::f`, but you can't *name* it with that path. For functions, this doesn't make much of a difference, but if it was a type instead, this would mean that that type could be in a public interface without any consumer being able to name that type.

Answer (score 0):

This allows you to have a fine-grained *scopes* of encapsulation. Consider the following example.

```rust
pub mod A {
    mod B {
        pub fn foo() {
            println!("foo");
        }
    }
    
    pub fn bar() {
        println!("calling foo");
        B::foo()
    }
}

fn main() {
    A::bar();
    
    // A::B is private. Can't call foo
    // A::B::foo();
}
```

You have a public module `A` and inside of it you have a private module `B` with helper functions. Functions in `A` can call functions from `B`, but callers outside of `A` cannot call its helper functions.

Comment: Technically, `pub` isn't needed for that, `pub(super)` would be enough.

Comment: Thank for you this answer - very clear. Essentially making a `mod` private hides any public functions from anything which is not "adjacent" to that module. ie: Adjacent things can call the public functions, but anything outside of that cannot because the module is public. Sorry I don't know the correct Rust terminology for "adjacent" but I hope it is clear what I mean by that?